# Why does the arrow notation of categorical limit go from right to left?

Tags: soft-question, notation, category-theory

Whilst studying some category theory, I was blindly using the notation $\lim_\leftarrow D$ for the limit of a diagram $D$ in some category $\mathcal{C}$ (as they are notated in MacLane, Awodey, my lectures etc.).

Why does the arrow go from right to left?

Is it because we think of the limit of a diagram as sitting on the left of the diagram (where the arrows in our diagram go from left to right)?

I sometimes think of a terminal object as being to the far right of a category, because everything can map into it. If limits had an arrow from left to right (like in analysis), I think I could justify this by saying "Well a limit is a terminal object in the category of cones, so it sits on the right". This makes me think that my 'reason' above is nonsense.

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know the reason for sure, but here is my guess.

The most basic (and historically important) examples of limits and colimits are those indexed by the natural numbers, ordered by $\geq$ (resp. $\leq$). In the case of limits, one takes diagrams of the form
$$\dotsc \dotsc \to A_2 \to A_1 \to A_0$$
and the limit goes to the left direction and therefore(?) is denoted by $\varprojlim A_i$.

Dually, the colimit of
$$B_0 \to B_1 \to B_2 \to \dotsc \dotsc$$
goes to the right direction and therefore(?) is denoted by $\varinjlim B_i$.

Notice that the limit of $A_0 \to A_1 \to \dotsc$ is $\varprojlim A_i = A_0$, which is "because" $A_0$ is already on the left.

Comment: also how do you Tex that $lim_\leftarrow$ so nicely?

Comment: \varprojlim and \varinjlim

Answer (score 4):

The universal property of the limit has certain arrows go *into* the limit.

Similarly,  the universal property of colimits has certain arrows come out of the colimit.

Comment: I didn't know that this is the reason for the notation. Do you have a reference for this or is this just your mnemonic? Often one writes $\varprojlim$ (resp. $\varinjlim$) and here it is not clear if the arrow goes out or into the limit (resp. colimit).